# NSString How convert hours to seconds

Tags: objective-c

I found How to convert seconds to 11:00:30.1 format but can't find how to convert hours in format 11:00:30.1 to seconds. Please give me some links.

Comment: Is your "11:00:30.1" input a form of string or do you have the input as numbers already?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSString *string = @"11:00:30.1";;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter= [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss.SS"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
NSTimeInterval seconds = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
```

Edit: Thanks to **Johan Kool** for pointing me at NSDateFormatter. Updated code for simplicity.

Comment: Are you aware of the `NSDateFormatter` class? Looks like you are reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: @johan-kool: Thanks, I somehow must have missed that one, back when I wrote that code. Updated the code for the sake of simplicity. Have an upvote!